# Apache Flink: How to easily restore state?

Tags: apache-flink

I'm deploying Flink as application cluster mode.
Deployment environment consists of two Kubernetes pod, one for the JobManager and one for the TaskManager (scalable).
JobManager pod hosts one container based on a Docker image that execute the command:

```
standalone-job.sh start-foreground --job-classname=${JOB_CLASS_NAME}
```

The deployment process is based on a CI-CD pipeline and works in this way.

1. Write the code
2. Git commmit and push
3. Jenkins pipeline starts JAR isbuilded
4. A new pod is created and the JAR is deployed on it

I cannot stop the previous application using savepoint, so I have to retain checkpoints after cancellation and try to use the last retained checkpoint to restore state.

The problem is that after code updates, the pipeline spreads a new pod with a new JAR with a completely new job with a new jobId.
The command to restore from checkpoint seems to be

```
 standalone-job.sh start-foreground --job-classname=${JOB_CLASS_NAME} --fromSavepoint /path/to/checkpoint
```

but `/path/to/checkpoint` is not fixed because contains the previous jobId that I cannot access.

Is there an automation to restore state without passing the checkpoint path?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using the [Apache Flink Kubernetes Operator](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-kubernetes-operator-docs-main/). Such automatism is offered there:

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-kubernetes-operator-docs-main/docs/custom-resource/job-management/#stateful-and-stateless-application-upgrades

Comment: Reading, seems that lastState would be the best solution, it requires a HA mode setup. This can be a problem for me.